# How to assign a table name to a variable and using the same inside immediate execute statement

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, dynamic-sql

I am trying to assign table name to a variable and to use the same inside execute immediate statement , please help me with the syntax inside execute statement

scenario is

I am trying to pass a table name as parameter in the procedure and am using them inside execute immediate to write into some other table .

please suggest me the syntax for in parameters and for the execute immediate statement.

My Procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE tep
AS
  v_sql VARCHAR2(1024) ;
  a     NUMBER;
  b     VARCHAR2(30) :='t_stg1_non_silicon_purchace_re';
BEGIN
  v_sql := q'[SELECT COUNT(*) FROM b ]';
  EXECUTE immediate v_sql INTO a;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( TO_CHAR(v_sql));
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( TO_CHAR(a));
END;
/
```

Comment: SO already has many answers on this topic. [Follow this link](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Boracle%5D+%22execute+immediate%22+%22table+name%22).  Which one actually fits your situation depends details you haven't provided.  But I suggest you browse some of these.  If they don't help you'll need to refine your question.

Comment: Please check for existing solutions before posting a question

Comment: create or replace procedure tep as
v_sql VARCHAR2(1024) ;
a number;
b varchar2(30) :='t_stg1_non_silicon_purchace_re';
begin
 v_sql := q'[SELECT COUNT(*) FROM b ]';
execute immediate v_sql into a;

 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(
         TO_CHAR(v_sql));
         
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(
         TO_CHAR(a)); 

         end;  i am trying this

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified what exactly you want to do with the table name in the execute immediate so see example below of how to "CREATE" a table.

```
DECLARE 
vTableName VARCHAR2(40 CHAR);
vSQL VARCHAR2(1000 CHAR);
BEGIN
    vTableName:='MY_TABLE_NAME';
    vSQL:='CREATE TABLE ' || vTableName || ' (COL1 NUMBER, COL2 NUMBER)';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE vSQL;
END;
/
```

Comment: please help me here create or replace procedure tep as
v_sql VARCHAR2(1024) ;
a number;
b varchar2(30) :='t_stg1_non_silicon_purchace_re';
begin
 v_sql := q'[SELECT COUNT(*) FROM b ]';
execute immediate v_sql into a;

 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(
         TO_CHAR(v_sql));
         
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(
         TO_CHAR(a)); 

         end;

Comment: You need to use the USING keyword when executing this statement to pass the name of the table to the SQL. v_sql := q'[SELECT COUNT(*) FROM :1 ]'; EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql INTO a1 USING b;

Comment: create or replace procedure tep as
v_sql VARCHAR2(1024) ;
a number;
b varchar2(30) :='t_stg1_non_silicon_purchace_re';
begin
v_sql := q'[SELECT COUNT(*) FROM using b ]'; EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql INTO a ;

 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(
         TO_CHAR(v_sql));
         
     /* DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(
         TO_CHAR(a)); */

         end;

Comment: Actually, I may be wrong. You may not be able to use the bind variables in this context. Instead construct your v_sql as follows: v_sql := '[SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' || b; Then, EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql INTO a1;

Comment: Great. Glad to hear it. Any chance of an up vote on my previous comment? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
This query may satisfy your requirement. Thanks

    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE tep
    AS
      v_sql VARCHAR2(1024) ;
      a     NUMBER;
      b     VARCHAR2(30) :='t_stg1_non_silicon_purchace_re';
    BEGIN
      v_sql := 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM'||' '||b;
      EXECUTE immediate v_sql INTO a;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( TO_CHAR(v_sql));
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( TO_CHAR(a));
    END;
```